# UITableView inside blurry UIView like Siri

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to reproduce a similar view like the one Siri uses, specifically when she's showing some content, which looks like a "blurry-ier" content over an already blurry view.

Something like this, here you can clearly see the difference between the background and the content (like in the wiki/twitter view) that Siri is showing

[image]

I need this solution to be compatible with iOS 7 and I know iOS 8 allows to blur stuff easily but can't use that solution. 
I already have the UIView with a blurry background, but I don't know how to highlight the content like Siri does so it's easier for the user to see what is part of the table and what is not.

Comment: Is it really blurrier or just a light gray overlay with some alpha?

Comment: Interesting.. I dont now why but I see it blurrier.What you said might be a posible solution, I'll try it out